# Hibernate - create subclass when persisting super class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem in creating proper hibernate mappings for my web application.

I have a table User (primary key is `id`).  The user table has data that doesn't change too often for a user.  I have another table user_editable_data that has data editable by the user.
The table structure is as below

User
id|username|password

user_editable_data
id|info1|info2

The id in user_editable_data is same as User.id

I have two entities (User and UserEditableData) corresponding to the tables.  My requirement is that i need to create an entry in user_editable_data table whenever an user is created.

I am able to do this successfully by using hibernate  mappings by following the tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/). But with that i should have an object of User in UserEditableData class which i dont want to use.

I tried using  mapping. But with that only the object of User is getting created when i persist User object.

Can someone suggest me a way to map User and UserEditableData such that when we persist/create User, UserEditableMapping should also get created with the same id as in User.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of UserEditableData and map both tables to the same class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667918/hibernate-mapping-two-tables-to-one-class) or [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/218948/ORM/java/Hibernate-Hibernate-Mapping-Multiple-Table). You can find the official documentation of the <join> tag in the [Hibernate Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html), section 5.1.20