# Hibernate Mapping - connecting table with no @Id

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, entity, hibernate-onetomany

I have three tables, `Member`, `Address` and `Mem_Addr`.
`Member` and `Address` entities are mapped / connected by `Mem_Addr` table. Many to Many.

I have the following entities for `Member` and `Address`:

```
@Entity 
@Table (name="Member")
public class Member{

    @Id  //....
    private Integer mem_id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable     (name = "Mem_Addr", 
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "addr_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mem_id"))
    Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>;
    ...
}
```

`Mem_Addr` table (It has not associated entity).

```
addr_id // (PK) Sequence
mem_id  // (FK to mem_id in Member table) 
....
....
```

`Address` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {

   private String addr_id; // Foreign Key to addr_id in Mem_addr table
   private String address1;
   ...
}
```

I do not have ID in the `Address` table/entity. (Please don't ask me about the design. Its not changeable right now.)

So when I load Members, I want to load all address locations for that member.

What is the solution?

**Edit:** More info...

Basically some `Member`s will have a new entry in `Mem_Addr` table. For each entry in `Mem_addr` table there will be an entry in `Address` table.

To get the address of a member, I need to refer Mem_Addr. Mem_Addr has `addr_id` as primary and Address has `addr_id` as foreign key.

Comment: Is there an addr_id in Address entity because I see in Mem entity you are calling it?

Comment: @Rika you are right.. I mistyped it. Corrected.

Comment: I think you probably can connect without Ids but it must be have Embeddable annotation, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk

Comment: @Rika: I think the @Embeddable approach won't work if the table you're trying to map is a foreign key to something else.  A Hibernate entity is supposed to be an independent, stand-alone thing, so Hibernate will try to insert a new row into `Address`, which will fail due to the unsatisfied FK constraint and be rolled back.

Comment: @Tim It probably can work if he makes the Mem_Addr into an entity, then make the String addr_id; in Address to MemAddr addr_id; then do the Embeddable thing, it should insert it properly with cascading

Comment: Hey Mr.Rave is it possible for you to make Mem_Addr into an entity?

Comment: @Rika, yes, I can, If need be. I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @Rika I don't need to do inserting with this. I just need loading of addresses along with members.. No inserts or updates.

Comment: @Rika You're right, it would be possible to map both classes and use @Embeddable to embed one within the other, but you shouldn't.  The purpose of Hibernate is to let you bridge the differences between your object model and your data model, including the ways where your data model is sub-optimal due to legacy issues, as it seems to be here.  Introducing an entity for `Mem_Addr` exposes the mismatch rather than hiding it, and ties the object model to the bad data model design.  The better solution is to use a single entity class (as OP intended), and map to the data model using @SecondaryTable.

Comment: Kevin, why did you change this to @OneToOne?  Do you really mean that, rather than @OneToMany?

Comment: @Tim, yes. I really mean that.

Comment: Then you should change the type to be `Address` instead of `Set<Address>`, since one-to-ones can have only a single associated value.  But based on your comments (e.g. "I want to load all address locations for that member."), I don't believe that's actually what you mean, even though you say it is.

Comment: Does it radically change any solution it may have if I use OneToOne vs OneToMany?

Comment: There shouldn't be a huge difference if you go with the SecondaryTable approach.  If you were going to take @Rika's approach that wouldn't allow updates/inserts, I don't believe you can use a join table with one-to-ones so it would make a difference, but since you're not going down that path it probably doesn't matter.  Though I'm not sure that OneToOne is legal on a collection; I've never tried to do that (it's semantically wrong, whether it works or not, so I've never wanted to), so you might hit problems, but if you do they should be easy enough for you to sort out.

Comment: Okay. may be I am lost. What is your suggested solution.. Assuming, its @OneToMany and leaving the tables updatable and insertable?

Comment: Map the `Address` entity to both the `Mem_Addr` and `Address` tables using the SecondaryTable annotation, as I described in my answer below.

Comment: OKay.. Let me check how that can be done..

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  Did the SecondaryTable approach give you what you needed, or did you end up doing something else?

Comment: @Tim I haven't tried this yet. I did not see a perfect example for my case in google search yet!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way around, Hibernate requires your table to have primary key.

You can check out [this document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id).

Answer (score 1):

Okay since, insertions and updates are not necessary, the following (in theory) should perhaps work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
class Address {

 @Id
 private AddressKey id;

 public void setId(AddressKey id) {
 this.id = id;
 }

 public void getId() {
 return id;
 }
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
class AddressKey implements Serializable {
   @Column(name = "addr_id")
   private String addrId; //also the underscore should be deleted

   @Column(name = "address_1")
   private String address1;



  }
```

This is a workaround found for tables that don't have Primary Keys. As you can see it pretty much makes a fake Id.

Comment: If we're not worried about insertions and updates, then why bother with the @Embeddable?  Just map `addr_id` as @Id and be done with it.  (Besides, `address1` isn't part of the primary key for the table, so I'm not sure why you've included it in the @Embeddable...)

Comment: But how do you map the Address to Members table. There is no link between those two. It may be a simple thing.. .. you get me.. I am a newbie to Hibernate :-)

Comment: For the record, though, I think it's a bad decision to intentionally map a Hibernate entity that can't be used to write to the database, even if you think you don't need that ability.  Odds are you will at some point, and even if you really never need them in production, what if you want to write some test data to a dummy database for use in unit tests?  I think that taking this approach would be a mistake when other approaches will also work and don't come with these drawbacks, but we all get to make our own choices so it's your call.

Comment: @Tim, thats a good point..May be I need to allow Insertions and Updates. I will go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `Mem_Addr` table is many-to-many, rather than one-to-many?  I don't see how a single `Address` could be associated with more than one `Member`...

Assuming it's actually one-to-many, map your `Address` entity to both the `Mem_Addr` and `Address` tables via the [@SecondaryTable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1758) annotation as described in [Hibernate Mapping Two Tables to One Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667918/hibernate-mapping-two-tables-to-one-class), mapping the id to `Mem_Addr.addr_id`, the `Member` via `Mem_Addr.mem_id`, and everything else via the other fields in `Address`.

I haven't done this, but I believe it will work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Mem_Addr", pkJoinColumns={
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="addr_id" referencedColumnName="addr_id")
})
class Address {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String addr_id;

    ....
}
```

Comment: Its possible. Because in Insurance domain, multiple customers can be in same address. Okay, if I assume its going to be @OneToMany, but your solution is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I haven't done this (thankfully I've always had schemas that were more reasonable than what you're stuck with), but you should be able to use the @SecondaryTable annotation for this, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667918/hibernate-mapping-two-tables-to-one-class.

Comment: Also, I agree that in the real world, it's possible to have multiple `Member`s for a single `Address`.  But I don't believe it's possible in your database schema (you'd have to create one `Address` object for each `Member` object, even though the values of that `Address` would be the same), which is why hopefully you'll be allowed to change that schema at some point in the future.

Comment: Okay. I am updating my question with more insight. I guess it may yeild a different solution from you. :-).

Comment: Nothing you added changes the solution here.  Because the primary key is in the `Mem_Addr` table, the `Address` class has to be mapped to it, but it also needs to be mapped to the `Address` table.  To map a single class to two tables, you'll want to use @SecondaryTable, as I suggested.